# Evaluating $\int_{1}^\infty\frac{1}{t^a\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$ for $a\geq 1$

Tags: improper-integrals

I know that the this integral converges, but I can't show it. And, how can I proceed to calculate its value?

$$\displaystyle \int_{1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{t^a\sqrt{t^2-1}} dt\qquad (a \geq 1)$$

Comment: i = 1 i'm sorry i edited it.

Comment: i tried computing its value using different values of a and for all $a\ge 1 $ it always converged.

Comment: It converges when $\displaystyle\Re\left(a\right) > 0$.

Comment: Did you try integration by parts ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\dd t \over t^{a}\root{t^{2} - 1}}\,\right\vert
_{\ \Re\pars{a}\ >\ 0}} 
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ \mapsto\ 1/t}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{1}^{0}
{-\dd t/t^{2} \over \pars{1/t}^{a}\root{1/t^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{t^{2}\ \mapsto\ t}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a/2 - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,{\Gamma\pars{a/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over\Gamma\pars{a/2 + 1/2}} =
\bbx{{\Gamma\pars{a/2} \over\Gamma\pars{a/2 + 1/2}}\,
{\root{\pi} \over 2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
I would do the substitution $$t=\frac1{\cos x}$$
When $t=1$, you have $x=0$, and for $t=\infty$ you get $x=\pi/2$. You also then have $\sin x\ge 0$ in this interval, so $$\sqrt{t^2-1}=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\tan x$$